# Cant get ion-input value properly with ngModel

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a  ion-input that i need to retrieve the value and pass it through a function inside a button. Im tryng with ngModel but its not working, how should i be doing this? i did some research and didnt find this example

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nomeNervo" name="nomeNervo"></ion-input> 
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>
        <button ion-button (click)="pushRow(nomeNervo.value)" color="danger">
            Inserir
        </button> 
    </ion-col>  
    </ion-row>
```

And this is my pushRow function

```
  pushRow(nome: String){
   this.usuario.nomeNervo = nome;
   this.nervos.push(this.usuario);
                 }
```

nervos is an array of any type and usuario a any object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass

```
<button ion-button (click)="pushRow(nomeNervo)" color="danger">
            Inserir
</button>
```